# SQL Azure Sync between two Azure databases doesn't preserve names

Tags: sql, azure

I'm trying to sync between two SQL Azure databases as a solution to the inability to do cross domain queries. Basically I have 5 tables in a small database which is updated very frequently, and I want the contents of those 5 tables into my main application database so I've created them both with identical schema in each.

The sync SEEMS to be working but what I end up with a load of tables in another schema, but nothing in my own tables

eg My tables  - dbo.ad, dbo.adgroup etc.

but I get datasync.ad, datasync.adgroup etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what we learn from this is patience.

Sql Azure sync created those datasync schema tables as a tracking mechanism for the sync. It can take a little while (approx 30 mins for me) before your data starts to appear, but appear it does.